# how to read streaming data in xml format (Pyspark)

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a large number of XML files coming in real-time in a folder in XML format. I have to read that XML, parse and write to parquet in append mode. And this will happen in Real-time using pyspark. How will I do that?

XML File example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Repository.xsl"?>

<Main id='EC84-A89C-HJCF6DF'>
<Collection>
  <fact><Name>Test</Name><tent filename="EDF.csv"><![CDATA[A,B,C,D,E
  -200,-99.65,-105.00,-95.00,B
  -180,-79.09,-85.00,-75.00,B ]]></tent></fact></Collection>
```

The output will look like this:

[image]

Though I have already done the transformation in pyspark, this time I wanted to accomplish this while reading the XML real-time. Please check the code below, that gave the output in image.

```
df2 = df.select(f.col('_id').alias('id'), 
f.explode("Collection").alias("Collection")).selectExpr("id", 
"Collection.*").select("id", 
f.explode('fact').alias('value')).selectExpr("id", "value.*").select(
    "id", f.split('tent', '\\n').alias('tent')).select("id", 
f.explode('tent')).select("id", 'col', f.size(f.split('col', 
',')).alias('size')).select("id", 'size', 'col').where("size = 
5").filter("col not like '%A%'").select("id", 'col').select("id", 
f.split('col', ',').alias('word'))

df3 = df2.select('id', *[df2['word'][i] for i in range(5)])
cols = ['id','A','B','C','D','E']
df3 = df3.toDF(*cols)
```

Comment: please help me with the pyspark code.(not well versed with scala)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Also, at which stage are you stuck and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @mike Please check the code above in pyspark. which will give you the o/p as present in image. I want to do it realtime using pyspark streaming.